# Chemmacros error: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr..."

Tags: chemmacros

When I load chemmacros I get the following error message (I don't understand it...):

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...egin \relax \d@llarend \endtemplate 
                                                  
l.62 \end{document}
                   
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

My very simplified test document, which works if I do Not load `{chemmacros}`, where I just want to print all the packages etc. in the pdf:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
%\usepackage{chemmacros}
\listfiles%

\AtEndDocument{\printfilelist}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}%
\ExplSyntaxOn%
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfilelist}{}{%
    \setlength{\LTleft}{\fill}%
    \setlength{\LTright}{\fill}%
    \begin{longtable}{@{}%
            >{\ttfamily}%
            L{0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep}%
            L{\widthof{9999/99/99}}%
            >{\raggedright}%
            p{0.7\textwidth-\widthof{9999/99/99}-3\tabcolsep}%
            @{}}%
        \toprule%
        \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries File~name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Date} & \bfseries File~info%
        \tabularnewline%
        \midrule%
        \endhead%
        \bottomrule%
        \endfoot%
        \Holou_print_filelist:%
    \end{longtable}%
}%
\tl_new:N \l_filelist_body_tl%
\tl_new:N \l_fileinfo_tl%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \Holou_print_filelist: {%
    \clist_map_inline:cn {@filelist}{%
        \Holou_print_fileinfo:n {##1}%
    }%
    \tl_use:N \l_filelist_body_tl%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \Holou_print_fileinfo:n #1 {%
    \regex_match:nnT { \.(sty|cls|tex|clo|fd|cfg|bbx|cbx|lbx|ldf|def|hak)\Z } {#1}{%
        \Holou_print_pkginfo:n {#1}%
    }%
}%
\cs_new_protected:Npn \Holou_print_pkginfo:n #1 {%
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_fileinfo_tl {ver@#1}%
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_fileinfo_tl {~} {&}%
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_filelist_body_tl {%
        \exp_not:N \seqsplit{#1}%
        &%
        \exp_not:V \l_fileinfo_tl%
        \exp_not:N \tabularnewline%
    }%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff%

\begin{document}
    
\end{document}
```

Here a picture, without `{chemmacros}`, for those who want to see what the code does: [image]

Now my question is why does it not work when I load `{chemmacros}`. Have I done something wrong? :D

Solution (edit): The problem was the &-symbol in the chemmacros file info, which I have just replaced now with e.g. `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_fileinfo_tl {&} {-}` before I myself add the &-symbol by replacing the first ~-symbol after the date. Thanks Ulrike. <3

Comment: I try compiling it locally and don't see any error

Comment: Side note, you *usually* don't need trailing `%` in expl3 environment, and I'd recommend programming TeX macros in Lua instead

Comment: @user202729 I tried it too online (https://www.overleaf.com/) and it worked there, so I asume it has to be the version I have installed on my laptop maybe (it's a way newer one from 2022/03/11, compared to the old one on overleaf.) Thanks, now I know it has to be on my end at least. :D

Comment: @user202729 do you have version v6.2a of chemmacros? (That's my version)

Comment: Seems you can do `\usepackage{chemmacros5}` or something to force a particular major version.

Comment: the fileinfo of chemmacros.sty contains a  `&` and so produces an additional cell: `\l_fileinfo_tl=2022/03/11&v6.2a comprehensive support for typesetting
chemistry documents (CN & SK).`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer wtf... hadn't thought about that. Seems like I can't just print it than. Thank you very much <3. That has answered my question than. :D

Comment: it helps to plant e.g. `\tl_show:N \l_fileinfo_tl` into the code to see what it is doing.

Comment: Yes, just old print debug...

Comment: By the way errorcontextlines might help here in terms of more useful traceback.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer . I now added something like that `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_fileinfo_tl {&} {-}`, above my other "replace_once", to be on the save side. :D

Comment: You can replace it with a &-catcode-other instead.

Comment: @user202729 you don't need errorcontextlines here (and imho it wouldn't help much). `! Extra alignment tab` means there is a & too much and so you only need to inspect the text to find out where it is from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments you get bitten by the `&` in the file info of `chemmacros`. You can get around this problem by stringifying the file info.

Replace

```
\tl_set_eq:Nc \l_fileinfo_tl {ver@#1}
```

by

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_fileinfo_tl { \tl_to_str:c {ver@#1} }
```

for example and your code works…

[image]